# Interstital ad won't load

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm trying  to get a interstital ad  and a banner ad to load when an activity is launched. The banner ad is working fine but the interstital ad is just not showing up. Can anyone help me? Here is my code from the onCreate() void.

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);

    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.bigAdID));

    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    if(interstitial.isLoaded()){
        interstitial.show();}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial

Because of their larger size, interstitial ads require more bandwidth on average than traditional banners. **To accommodate this, the recommended approach is to have apps load them in advance of when they will be displayed. This helps ensure that an ad is ready to go when the time comes to display one.**

You should wait for interstitial to be loaded.

change your code

```
if(interstitial.isLoaded()){
        interstitial.show();}
```

to

```
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
         if(interstitial.isLoaded()){
        interstitial.show();}
});
```

On a side note - it's not good practice to show interstitial ads as soon as activity is loaded, wait for an appropriate action from user and show it https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en